# Typescript not recognizing optional props in Vue 3 component, used in Astro Project

Tags: html, typescript, vuejs3, astrojs

I'm working on an Astro project using Vue components and Typescript. I have a component with optional props:

```
<script setup>

const props = defineProps({
  sources: { type: Array as PropType<string[]>, required: true },
  height: { type: [Number, String], default: 400 },
  width: { type: [Number, String], default: 900 },
  autoSlide: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  transitionTime: { type: Number, default: 0.4 },
  controls: Boolean,
  pages: Boolean,
});

</script>
```

When I use the component inside an Astro page skipping some optional props:

```
<MyComponentWithOptionalProps sources={imgSources} autoSlide={2000}  controls pages client:only="vue"/>
```

I can see this error on vscode:

```
Type '{ sources: string[]; autoSlide: number; controls: true; pages: true; "client:only": string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { readonly sources: any; readonly height: string | number; readonly width: string | number; readonly autoSlide: number; readonly transitionTime: number; readonly controls: boolean; readonly pages: boolean; }'.
  Type '{ sources: string[]; autoSlide: number; controls: true; pages: true; "client:only": string; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ readonly sources: any; readonly height: string | number; readonly width: string | number; readonly autoSlide: number; readonly transitionTime: number; readonly controls: boolean; readonly pages: boolean; }': height, width, transitionTime Ts
```

[image: Error]

This error only appears in vscode and when I run `npm run build`, but not when I run `npm run dev`. I seems that the optional props are no optional in the Astro page.

The project was created with Astro cli and I didn't touch anithing on the astro.config.

I don't know if it is an integration error, or an Astro's thing or a Vue issue, or typescript or I'm missing something.

Any one can figure out what is going on?